# tailwind css custom class passed as props is not overriding the already applied class

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

I am using tailwind classes and below is my code. some people suggested to use classNames so used that as well, so similar code in both the newer and older format

```
const backgroundColor = disabled ? "bg-secondary-500" : "bg-green-700";
```

```
className={classNames(
        "w-20 my-2 p-2 text-white rounded capitalize hover:ease-in hover:scale-110 hover:duration-200",
        customClass,
        backgroundColor,
        { "pointer-events-none": true }
      )}
```

```
 className={`w-20 my-2 p-2 text-white bg-green-700 rounded capitalize 
             hover:ease-in hover:scale-110 hover:duration-200 
             ${disabled ? "pointer-events-none bg-secondary-500" : ""} 
             ${customClass}`}
```

so in my customClass I have "w-60". but "w-20" is only getting applied. even it is happening for "bg-green-700" and I wanted it to be "bg-secondary-500" for disabled: true

so my disabled is coming as true and **pointer-event-none** is getting applied but **secondary** class is overridden by **green** class

I checked the DOM and both the bg class and both the width classes are available in the below order

```
<button class="w-20 my-2 p-2 text-white bg-green-700 rounded capitalize 
    hover:ease-in hover:scale-110 hover:duration-200 w-60 
    bg-secondary-500 pointer-events-none">View Docs
</button>
```

so if anyone has any idea this is happening, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For merging Tailwind classes use https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge instead of `classNames`

```js
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge'

// ...

className={twMerge(
  "w-20 my-2 p-2 text-white bg-green-700 rounded capitalize hover:ease-in hover:scale-110 hover:duration-200",
  disabled && "pointer-events-none bg-secondary-500",
  customClass
)}
```

Comment: sure let me try

Comment: this is exactly was needed, so basically it is overriding the class coming later with the previously applied one and so w-20 is getting replaced with w-60 and so does background colors

Answer (score 0):

Here if I understood correctly , you want `bg-secondary-500` when button is disabled. This can be done by this

```
className={`w-20 my-2 p-2 text-white rounded capitalize
             hover:ease-in hover:scale-110 hover:duration-200
             ${disabled ? "pointer-events-none bg-secondary-500" : "bg-green-500 pointer-events-auto"}
             `}
```

However you need to add any condtion if you want to change from `w-20` to `w-60`. Else simply use `w-60`.

Comment: for background color its fine and whatever you have suggested will work but this is my button component which has w-20 as the default class and one of the button has larger text so while importing this <Button /> I am just passing w-60 as the customClass

Comment: Let replace it with `w-full` ,then no need to pass anything

Comment: this is what is my understanding for width, please correct me whereever I am wrong.                 

w-full is like width:100%, so that will again depend upon where the button is placed, as if it is bottom of the page and considering that as a block level element it is take the whole page width as 100% but if it is inside some other div which has a defined width it will take that div width as its 100% width

Comment: the above answer with twMerge it is working for me

Comment: So replace it with `w-auto` once. Then it will take the width needed by its content

Comment: w-auto worked for width but again I need to have some condition for bg-color as for that we dont have anything generic like w-auto, but this was a good solution, so when ever it is just a matter of sizes I can use w-auto or some similar otherwise "tw-merge"
thanks